# Big O notation algebra

Tags: big-o

I have a couple of questions regarding some algebra using big O notation:

if `f(n)=O(g(n))`

is `log(f(n)) = O(log(g(n)))`?

is `N^{f(n)}=O(N^{g(n)})`? (where N is any real number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is `log(f(n)) = O(log(g(n)))` ? No, it is not essential, for example:

  `f(n)= n`  and  `g(n) = n^2`. Here `f(n) = O(g(n))`
- Is `N^{f(n)}=O(N^{g(n)})` ? No, this is also not true as

for two algorithms , the ratio may remain constant, but the ratio of each raised to certain power will never be constant.

Take

f
(
n
) = 2
n
and
g
(
n
) =
n
.

It is true that `2n` is `O(n)`. But consider

[image: limit to prove the falseness]

This limit is not bounded - it goes to infinity as n goes to infinity. So,

`2^2n` is not `O(2n)` i.e. `2f(n)` is not `O(2g(n))` in this case.