# Prove or disprove the following implication (Big O Notation)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, implication

I couldn't prove this:

`f(n) = O(g(n))` implies `f(n)^k = O(g(n)^k)`

`where k is element of the natural, positiv numbers`

I've found similar examples on the internet. But I'm not sure if it's right to implement those solutions for this example.

Comment: that's the similar example I've found
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361448/i-need-help-proving-that-if-fn-ogn-implies-2fn-o2gn

Comment: Pleasantries will be removed. Rolling back my edits will have no effect as others will take my place.

Comment: 1 = O(n) but 1^{-1} is not O(n^{-1})

Comment: sorry for the edit. Won't happen again

Comment: @PaulHankin - k is an element of the natural, positiv numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to the [definition of big-o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

```
f(n) = O(g(n)) <=> \exists M \in R+,
                   \exists n_0 \in N,
                   such that:
                   \forall n > n_0
                   |f(n)| < M.|g(n)|
```

It is obvious that if `k > 0` then `|f(n)|^k < (M.|g(n)|)^k`.

If `k < 0`, the relation is inversed.

Comment: considering the big-o notation, I've found another interesting problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492509/big-o-notation-algebra/23493414#23493414
I only need to know if the prove of the second question is correct?